# Ubuntu Server 14.04.3 update problems

Tags: apt, upgrade, updates, tr

using Ubuntu Server 14.04.3. apt-update & upgrade stuck on tr.archive.ubuntu.com 
It's responding so slow and can't download packages.

Answer (score 0):

Wait for the connectivity to your mirror to improve, or use another one. The mirror list is [here](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archivemirrors).

To change your mirror, edit your `/etc/apt/sources.list` to change `tr.archive.ubuntu.com` to the URL of your desired mirror, for example for [this one](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+mirror/netinternet-ubuntu-archive-mirror) it would be `mirror.ni.net.tr`. You can also use a one-liner like this:

```
printf ',s/tr\.archive\.ubuntu\.com/mirror\.ni\.net\.tr/\nw\n' | sudo ed /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Then run `sudo apt-get update` again to refresh the packages list from the new mirror.